# How can I strip these (â?²s) type of characters with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am developing an application using CodeIgniter/MySQL. Last night I stored a title into my database
"HTML5′s placeholder Attribute".
After storing when I retrieve from database for display it shows some strange characters like this:
"HTML5â?²s placeholder Attribute".

How I can avoid these strange characters?

Comment: Likely an error with mismatched character encoding. CodeIgniter should be handling this for you hoever. What is the encoding of your database and what encoding is output? (You should probably have ` $config['charset'] = "UTF-8";` in your application's `config.php`.)

Comment: @MichaelMior In my application's config.php my character set is $config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';

Comment: Can you confirm that the correct charset is being used in the page when it's output? Also, try connecting to your database and using `SET NAMES utf8;` and then retrieving the affected row to make sure it's stored properly.

Comment: @MichaelMior this the sample Url of my application http://www.seekphp.com/look/phpquery-jquery-port-to-php/1758 and I am using HTML charset=UTF-8" and Database collection is "utf8_bin"

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to make sure both the database table you are storing data is set to store in UTF-8 as well as the html page that displays the data should also be explicitly set to UTF-8 encoding.

Your example application URL (seekphp.com/look/phpquery-jquery-port-to-php/1758) shows (via firebug for firefox):

```
Response Headers
Date    Sat, 14 Jan 2012 06:26:31 GMT
Server  Apache/2.2.19 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.19 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.2.17
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Connection  Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Content-Type    text/html
```

but a properly UTF-8 encoded output will show the last line to be

```
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

You can encode your HTML through outputting a meta tag in the document HEAD section:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

or you can have PHP set this in a header:

```
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: I set my table Collection to "utf8_bin" and HTML charset=UTF-8". But same problem is occurs.

Comment: I have this tag in my head section, But problem is not solved.

Comment: Just because you set UTF-8 in a meta tag, doesn't mean the page is actually served that way ... right? That said, the page the original author linked to looks OK to me (as far as what encoding is being served).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I was copying data from a text editor and pasting it in phpmyadmin. If you're doing this then your text editor might be using different encoding. I suggest you copy the data into a simple text editor like a notepad and manually replace the apostrophes. Manually replace ‘ with ' and it should work fine.

Comment: Sorry, in my last sentence you should see two different apostrophes. Similar to what is shown here:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe
Replace the "curved" apostrophe if you have it in your data.

Comment: I paste the line in my text editor "HTML5′s placeholder Attribute" and then submit to phpmyadmin. It becomes "HTML5â?²s placeholder Attribute". So how i can make this (′) an HTML entity or strip from my line?

Comment: 1) First copy and paste in Notepad.
2) Delete the  (′) and then add the proper (').
3) Now copy and paste in phpmyadmin.


See if that works. Afterwards, you may want to change the text encoding on your text editor.

Answer (score -1):

i have an issue related with the utf-8 charset. I've been all around the web (well, not entirely) but for quite awhile now and the best advice was and is to set the header charset to "UTF-8".

However, I  was developing my web application locally on my machine using xampp (and sometimes wamp so as to get a distinction of the two when it came to debugging my code). Everything was working great =). But as soon as i uploaded it online, the result was not all that jazzy (the kind of errors you would get if you had set the headers to a different charset like "iso-8859-1"). 
Every header in my code has UTF-8 as the default charset, but i still got the same "hieroglyphic thingies". Then you guys gave me the idea that the issue isn't my code but the php.ini that was running it.. Turns out my local machine was running php 5.5 and the cpanel where i had uploaded my web application was running native php 5.3. 
Well, when i changed the version of php that my cpanel was set by default to PHP 5.5, believe you me guys =) it worked like a charm just like as if i was right there at the localhost of machine.

**NOTE**: Please, if you got the same problem as i did, just make sure your PHP is 5.5 version.. I'm posting this coz i feel you guys. Cheers!

Comment: This entire answer could be replaced with "Use PHP 5.5". The rest is unnecessary fluff.