# How to insert HTML entities in MySQL using CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, html-entities

I am creating an application using CodeIgniter/MySQL. The problem is that when I store a text with Quotes or Apostrophe. It stores an Blank value to MySQL database.

```
function add_article($title, $desc){
        $data = array(
            'title' => htmlentities($title, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"),
            'desc' => htmlentities($desc, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")
        );
        if($this->db->insert('articles', $data)){
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
}
```

The character set of my table "articles" is "utf8" and COLLATE is utf8_unicode_ci. And HTML character set is also UTF-8. what's wrong? Please help me, and thanks in advance. If i don't use htmlentities() function i face two problems which i mention in my comments below:

Comment: Why are you using `htmlentities()` for something that's being stored in your database? That function is for escaping HTML, you use it on your *output*.

Comment: @Madmartigan Because if don't use this, I face these problems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864127/how-i-can-convert-this-character-to-html-entities-using-php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860407/how-can-i-strip-these-as-type-of-characters-with-php

Comment: @Madmartigan Please read my problems and then answer me

Comment: I don't have an answer, which is why I didn't post one, but I wanted to comment about the side issue. There's no actual reason to encode to HTML entities in this context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have problems either on *input* or on *output*.

#### On Input

First of all, make sure that the string you receive actually *is* utf-8.

- If you received the data from a form, add `accept-encoding="utf-8"` to the `form` element.
- Verify that your input string could be a valid utf-8 stream with `TRUE===mb_check_encoding($string, 'UTF-8')`
- Check that the byte sequence is as expected by counting characters: `mb_strlen($string, 'UTF-8')` should return the same number of characters as what you see, and a number less than `strlen($string)` (which counts bytes).

In your `application/config/database.php`, ensure you have these two settings for your database connection:

```
$db[$dbgroupname]['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db[$dbgroupname]['dbcollat'] = "utf8_unicode_ci";
```

Replace `$dbgroupname` with the group name of your connection (e.g., `'default'`).

Don't use `htmlspecialchars` or `htmlentities` on data before you store it. Use those on output, in your views.

#### On Output

Ensure that whatever you are using to *view* the data that comes out of your database expects a utf-8 encoding.

For html, make sure your `Content-Type` header includes `charset=utf8` and your html document's `head` looks like this:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Check your results in multiple browsers. Some browsers do charset sniffing and might choose a different charset than what you declare. If so, this means that something on your page is not valid UTF-8--find that thing and eliminate.

If you are using some kind of database viewer (PHPMyAdmin, Navicat, etc), make sure the connection is configured to expect utf-8.

Comment: I counts the characters. There is a difference b/w mb_strlen($string, 'UTF-8')=29 and strlen($string)=31. String is "HTML5′s placeholder Attribute"

Comment: If i don't use the htmlentities(). My string becomes HTML5â?²s placeholder Attribute

Comment: Yes, but *where* does it become that? The very thing you are using to *view* the string may be corrupting it!

Comment: But it save in database with the same view like "HTML5â?²s placeholder Attribute"? What should i do now? i think problem is (′).

Comment: Please follow the steps on the "On Output" section of my answer. What you are using to view the string in the database may itself not understand "UTF-8". In other words, it may be *stored* in the database correctly, only *displaying* incorrectly.

Comment: You can see live example of my application http://www.seekphp.com/look/html5s-placeholder-attribute/1754

Comment: The string you are outputting (seen in view-source in the browser) is `HTML5&acirc;?&sup2;s placeholder Attribute`. This means it has already been improperly re-encoded by `htmlentities`. What you need to do is *not* use `htmlentities`!

Comment: But it's not encoded by me. It is encode automatically by CodeIgniter.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6737/discussion-between-francis-avila-and-rizwan-khan)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
Add this mysql query in the *`system/database/DB.php`* file at the end of DB function. (before  `return $DB;` ) .

```
$DB->simple_query('SET NAMES \'utf8\'');
```

Comment: I try the query but getting same problem.

Comment: problem is mentioned in my question. and in two questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864127/how-i-can-convert-this-character-to-html-entities-using-php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860407/how-can-i-strip-these-as-type-of-characters-with-php

Comment: This is unnecessary. Codeigniter does this for you in `mysql_driver.php`, `db_set_charset()` method, which is run as part of connection initialization.